# Laravel line break in message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, message, line-breaks

How do I do a line break in a message.

I tried following

```
$request->session()->flash('message', "first line \r\n second line");
$request->session()->flash('message', "first line <br> second line");
```

but they did not work, how do I accomplish this?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-get-html-in-response-session-flash-or-redirect-with-messages

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `<br>` but when displaying the messages, use unescaped echoing:

```
{!! session('message') !!}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#displaying-data

Answer (score 6):

You can try:

```
{!! 'first line <br> second line' !!}
```

**Output**

```
first line
second line
```

And

```
{!! nl2br(e('first line <br> second line')) !!}
```

**Output**

```
first line <br> second line
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use escaped echoing, you can try:

```
@foreach(explode('<br>', session('message')) as $msg)
{{ $msg }}
@if(!$loop->last)
<br>
@endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Displaying Unescaped Data in laravel like this.

```
{!! $message !!}
```